# Add product's brand name attribute on product page

Tags: attributes, magento2

I am trying to add the brand name in product view page, before the product name.
[image]
I tried to  modify the title.phtml under view file but couldn't get any success. Please suggest the way to show the brand name attribute on product page.
Thanks[image]

My code structure is as follow:

layout.xml->

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © zesh.com - All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.mailto" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addto" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist" name="view.addto.wishlist"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist" name="view.addto.wishlist.bottom"
                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.wrap" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view-info.phtml" before="-">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.social.share" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/social.phtml" after="-" />
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.media">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.discount.percent" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/discount_percent.phtml" after="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="product.info.main" destination="product.info.wrap" />
        <move element="product.info.media" destination="product.info.wrap" />
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.wrap" />
        <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.wrap" />
        <move element="product.info.sku" destination="product.info.wrap" />
        <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final" />
        <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.price" after="product.info.stock.sku" />
    </body>
</page>
```

my view-info.phtml is as follow:

```
<?php
$_mbHelper = $this->helper('Zesh\MbFrame\Helper\Data');
$productLayout = $_mbHelper->getConfig('mbconfig/product_view/product_layout');
$social = $_mbHelper->getConfig('mbconfig/product_view/share_social');
?>
<div class="product-info-main-top product-info-main">
    <?php if ($social) : ?>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
            <?= $this->getChildHtml('page.main.title') ?>
            <div class="info-after-title">
                <?= $this->getChildHtml('product.info.review') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?= $this->getChildHtml('page.main.title') ?>
    <div class="info-after-title">
        <?= $this->getChildHtml('product.info.review') ?>
        <?= $this->getChildHtml('product.info.sku') ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
<?php if ($productLayout) : ?>
<div class="product-info-main-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4">
            <?= $this->getChildHtml('product.info.media') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-5">
            <?= $this->getChildHtml('product.info.main') ?>
            <?= $_mbHelper->getCategoryStore($block->getProduct()); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-xl-3">
            <div class="sidebar-product-wrap">
                <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('sidebar-product')->toHtml(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
<div class="product-info-main-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
            <?= $this->getChildHtml('product.info.media') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
            <?= $this->getChildHtml('product.info.main') ?>
            <?= $_mbHelper->getCategoryStore($block->getProduct()); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Brand's name on product page.